# In Express.js, I am not able to use my static resourses in my root route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

How do I apply the styles or use images in my webpage for example root route that are stored in assets folder?
And in my code I have `app.use(express.static('assets');`
Note:I have styles.css file located at assets/styles.css.

My code is provided down below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('assets'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("hello dogs!!");
});
app.get('/home', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
    res.render('contact');

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: show your project dir structure

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/GViEuMG.png

Comment: Your root route will only return `"hello dogs!!"` If you want the root route to return a page then don't do `res.send("hello dogs!!");`. Instead do something like `res.render('root');` and create a file `view/root.ejs` that has a `<link>` tag to load your CSS from `/styles.css`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'assets')));
```

Dont forget to include npm module `path`:

```
var path = require('path')
```

Comment: My original code works like if I hit url at https:localhost:8080/styles.css 

In network tab I can see my css file getting loaded .My problem is how do i apply my styles.css in my web page for example to my root Route.
my css has *{ color:red} but it is not applying to root route .Where exactly I made mistake

Comment: how are you including css in your html file?